# Use :hover to modify the css of another class?

Tags: javascript, css, class, hover

Is there a way to modify the css for one class when hovering on an element from another class using only css ?

Something like:

```
.item:hover .wrapper { /*some css*/ }
```

Only 'wrapper' is not inside 'item', it's somewhere else.

I really don't want to use javascript for something this simple, but if I have to, how would I do it ? Here's my failed attempt:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0].onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0].style.background="url('some url')";";
```

There's only one element of each class. Don't know why they didn't use IDs when they made the template, but that's just how it is and I can't change it.

[Edit]

It's a menu. Each menu element has a distinct class. When you hover on the element a submenu pops up to the right. It's like an overlay, when I use the 'Inspect Element' tool I can see that the whole website html changes when the submenu is active(meaning there's nothing but the submenu). The class I call 'wrapper' has the css that controls the background for the submenu. There's really no connection that I can see between the two classes.

Comment: You dont want to use `getElementsByClassName` since it is not supported by every browser.

Comment: No. CSS doesn't allow non-nested elements to affect each other. You'll have to use Javascript for this.

Comment: _"somewhere else"_ : exactly where? if `.item` were a previous sibling you could do `.item:hover ~ .wrapper { ... }`

Comment: Your best bet is to show us your menu HTML so we can determine straight up if you can select it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible in CSS at the moment, unless you want to select a child or sibling element (trivial and described in other answers here).

For all other cases you'll need JavaScript. jQuery and frameworks like Angular can tackle this problem with relative ease.

[Edit]

With the new CSS (4) selector [:has() guide from CSS4.Rocks (archived by Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170720075238/http://css4.rocks:80/relational-pseudo-class.php) and [:has() guide from MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), you'll be able to target parent elements/classes, making a CSS-Only solution viable in the near future!

Comment: After briefly reading up on `:has` it leaves me with the impression that it only operates on the children in the current scope. How would you target a parenting element using `:has`?

Comment: @MarcusRiemer This is a rather old question of mine, I might not have worded the description very well back then, but what would have helped me is something like the following: `.common_parrent:has(.item:hover) .content {/*...*/}`

Answer (score 126):

There are two approaches you can take, to have a hovered element affect (`E`) another element (`F`):

1. `F` is a child-element of `E`, or
2. `F` is a later-sibling (or sibling's descendant) element of `E` (in that `E` appears in the mark-up/DOM *before* `F`):

To illustrate the first of these options (`F` as a descendant/child of `E`):

```
.item:hover .wrapper {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}​
```

To demonstrate the second option, `F` being a sibling element of `E`:

```
.item:hover ~ .wrapper {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}​
```

In this example, if `.wrapper` was an immediate sibling of `.item` (with no other elements between the two) you could also use `.item:hover + .wrapper`.

[JS Fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4vaY6/1/).

References:

- [CSS 2.1 selectors, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors).

Comment: You helped me out, in 2015. :D

Comment: You made my day.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

You can do it by making the following CSS. you can put here the css you need to affect child class in case of hover on the root

```css
.root:hover    .child {
   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Provided .wrapper is inside .item, and provided you're either not in IE 6 or .item is an a tag, the CSS you have should work just fine.  Do you have evidence to suggest it isn't?

EDIT:

CSS alone can't affect something not contained within it.  To make this happen, format your menu like so:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="destination">menu text</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menuitem">
                <a href="destination">part of pull-out menu</a>
... etc ...
```

and your CSS like this:

```
.menu .menu {
    display: none;
}

.menu .menuitem:hover .menu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    // likely need to set top & left
}
```

Comment: They state that "Only 'wrapper' is not inside 'item', it's somewhere else."

Answer (score -3):

You can do this.
When hovering to the `.item1`, it will change the `.item2` element.

```
.item1 {
  size:100%;
}

.item1:hover
{
   .item2 {
     border:none;
   }
}

.item2{
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Comment: this syntax did not work for me...  "missing a selector in the style rule.".  Could you post a working example?

Comment: @JasonD Same for me, the syntax also didn't work.