# css :hover effect on current and previous elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have many unordered lists of 5 li in each like

```
 <ul class="Rank">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to change `background-color` of current `li:hover` element and all previous `li` elements in that list. Suppose, if I hover over 3rd `li` then 3rd, 2nd and 1st li should have `background-color:#00f;`

I can do it in jQuery or JavaScript, but I want it in pure CSS. Currently following this article: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

I can change background of currently hovered `li` element with this `.Rank li:hover` but cannot understand how can I change `background-color` of the previous elements of that current `.Rank` list.

From above article I also learnt to change background until `nth-chid` but cannot figure out how to apply `:hover` on it.

```
.Rank li:nth-child(-n+5)
{
    background-color:#00f;
}
```

Comment: There is no previous sibling selector. It cannot be done with just CSS, use javascript

Comment: @ZachSaucier there is previous sibling select as I said in last code. It may be not completely previous sibling selector but can do the job but cannot figure out how to apply hover effect on it. My Last code works good in Previous sibling changing background.

Comment: The selector you provide doesn' select previous elements just target child nodes. with that limit

Comment: You can also use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/): [JImlD.](http://codepen.io/shhade/pen/JImlD)

Comment: @ZachSaucier we got the Einstein to find how apple fell on earth. Thanks to all

Comment: If Einstein found Apple theory then what Newton did?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/PLBYG/2/

or

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/PLBYG/3/

```
ul.rank {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.rank > li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: background-color 350ms;
}

ul.rank:hover > li {
    background-color: #00f;
}

ul.rank > li + li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

ul.rank > li:hover ~ li {
    background: #ccc;
}

ul.rank > li + li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
}
```

or!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/PLBYG/4/

```
ul.rank {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I love these CSS chanllenges!

Comment: WOW! Supperb @coma. You are the like the Einstein of CSS :). Love you man

Comment: I can't believe it because everyone else was saying it's impossible without Javascript and here comes the Daddy

Comment: u r welcome. I just hate to think to do something with js if it sounds like it can be done with css. By the way you must admit that you earned 75 in just few minutes LOLs! Thanks again for your time

Comment: @coma Einstein Sir can you help me in changing other Class when hover over other class like stated in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class without using javascript or jquery. Please I need your help because everyone says it is not possible

Comment: Hi there!, I think David Thomas is right, those are the only ways to accomplish something like that using only CSS. Maybe you should provide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my answer for reference (to those who come viewing this later like I did).
Here is a solution that doesn't use `:before` or `:after`.

http://jsfiddle.net/nLCZK/

It uses `float: right` for all the `li`s, and you also have to put the `li`s in opposite order you want them to appear.