# Hovering over multiple Content to expand

Tags: css, hover, transition

I have a problem, so, bellow my header are my menu boxes who will expand while hovering over them and reveal the content. I have 3 boxes so far, but how I manage to make transition when I hover on 1 box that the other 2 boxes resize/reposition so that the first box (mainCOntent) expands and the reader can have a nice view on it. The same should go for all boxes when hovering over them. Please help.

```
<div id="mainContent">Content goes here</div>
  <aside id="biographie">
    <h1>Content goes here</h1>
    </aside>
<div id="projects" class="clearOne">Content goes here<div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainContent {

height: 250px;
width: 200px;
float: left;
font-family: cuprum;
line-height: 25px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
opacity: 0.5;
display: block;
overflow-y: hidden;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
padding-left: 5px;
text-align: left;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(309deg,rgba(250,65,255,0.45) 0%,rgba(255,116,234,0.19) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(141deg,rgba(250,65,255,0.45) 0%,rgba(255,116,234,0.19) 100%);
}

#mainContent:hover {
-webkit-transform: 2;
-o-transform: 2;
transform: 2;
-webkit-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
width: 600px;
height: 350px;
margin-top: 5px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
vertical-align: middle;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#projects {
background-color: rgba(234,197,244,0.14);
height: 350px;
width: 454px;
float: left;
padding-top: 26px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-bottom: 90px;
font-family: cuprum;
line-height: 25px;
left: 352px;
position: absolute;
top: 405px;

}
#biographie {
float: left;
width: 136px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0px 5px;
position: relative;
font-family: cuprum;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
left: 2px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
overflow-y: hidden;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(181,217,240,0.17)      0%,rgba(190,133,232,0.27) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(181,217,240,0.17) 0%,rgba(190,133,232,0.27) 100%);
}
```

Comment: Please narrow your code down to [the minimum, which still demonstrates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is quite a lot of code, and I'm sure not all is needed to demonstrate this effect.

Comment: @Joeytje50 - It's really not that much code (it's only four declarations and a small HTML snippet). Posting a working http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating the problem would be better.

Comment: Sorry it's my first time using this. I will try to narrow it down

Comment: You posted many codes ,, and we can't understand it.
Now your website looks like this..
[link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kEPmL/show/)..
and now let us to know what you need

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36h36/4/ I tryed up to do this in jsfiddle. I'm new to html, I'm trying to learn this. Thank you

Comment: @ShameelKadannamanna my main goal is how to edit the height, width, positioning of the other content boxes when I hover over the first box (from the left). Then I would apply that to hover state for all boxes.

Comment: I think better is using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think better is using javascript. or jquery..
or read this page
[Use :hover to modify the css of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class)

&

I used this jquery code

```
$("#mainContent").hover(
    function(){
        $("#projects").css({"width":200,"height":200});
        $("#biographie").css({"width":200,"height":200});
    },function(){
        $("#projects").css({"width":100,"height":100});
        $("#biographie").css({"width":100,"height":100});
});
```

Look this http://jsfiddle.net/36h36/6/

Comment: Oh, I only started to learn jquery. So should I just stop with this design? The idea was that each of those boxes acts as pages (Home, biograhie, projects, contact etc), and when loading page they would have some random shapes, when hovering on, let's say "Home" box, it would have an animation of expanding and the box and text gets visible, while at the same time the other boxes change shape so that all gets organized and fit into the "wrapper". This is what I had in mind, but I guess I need to learn more about jquery. Thank you