# how to change the background of a css-class by hover a button?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I would like to change the background image of a div by hover a button. This is my key:

```
.content-portfolio {
    background-image: url(../files/portfolio/event.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#event-button a:hover{

}
```

I dont really know how to do it, I hope you help me!

Best regards!

Comment: You need to show the HTML as well.

Comment: With hover over `#event-button a` you want to change background of `.content-portfolio`? Unless they are linked together somehow you can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty hard to do just with css. You probably could use some javascript to do that. But, I found a way to do what you want if your div was an immediate sibling of your button (with no other elements between the two).

The code would look like this:

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me !" />
<div id="testDiv">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#btn:hover + #testDiv {
    background-color: red;
}

#testDiv {
    border-style: solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The operator "+" or "~" will apply the css to the next sibling element.
Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rTGH/) that show you the tricks.

If you just remove the "+" it will apply the css to descendant/child of the left element. For more information you can check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to change `.content-portfolio`'s background when you hover on `event-button` right? You get it right by giving the button an `id` and not a `class`, but you **can't** affect other elements with css `selectors` if they're not related in some way. Alternatively, it's easier to affect other elements if they have ids instead of classes, specially if they don't have any kind of  hierarchy. You'll need to use a `javascript` solution for this ([**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6y2J/4/)):

**HTML**:

```
<a href="javascript:img()">
    <div id="EventButton">Click me to change the bg</div>
</a>
<div id="ContentPortfolio">I'm the content</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#ContentPortfolio  {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

#EventButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
function img() {
    if (ContentPortfolio.style.backgroundImage == 'url(http://goo.gl/PMqslv)') {
        ContentPortfolio.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://goo.gl/AJm0rS)';
    } else {
        ContentPortfolio.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://goo.gl/PMqslv)';
    }    
    return false;
}
```

In this approach I changed your id names so I can refer to them directly, instead of using the `document.getElementById`, but if your name contains dashes `-` or if this doesn't work on your browser, you should use the before mentioned function.

Comment: Please, have the courtesy to state what is wrong with an answer when you address a downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but im pretty sure `typeof ContentPortfolio === 'undefined'`

Comment: @DannyHearnah No, in fact typeof(ContentPortfolio) === 'object'. Did you check the fiddle? It is a reference to the element with that Id. But anyway, I've also suggested the use of the `getElementById` in case this doesn't work on his browser. It was just for the sake of a simple and clean answer.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you want to change background image of `.content-portfolio` this is the way to do it:

```
.content-portfolio:hover {
    background-image: url(../files/portfolio/event.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/y8tRd/

Comment: This won't change the background image of `.content-portfolio` but that of a child element.

Comment: @putvande Yes, it'll change the background of any element with the class `content-portfolio` when it's hovered.

Comment: No it doesn't. See the space between `.content-portfolio` and `:hover`? If there wasn't a space it would change the background of all `.content-portfolio`s but with it, it won't.

Comment: @putvande yes you're right the space was my mistake. fixed :)

Comment: @putvande I think it was a typo, not intentional. And if you were sure, what prevented you just to say that it won't because of the space?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
.content-portfolio{width:400px; height:400px; background:url(http://somdow.com/images/sitePortThumbs/saia-sushi-ft-lauderdale-sushi-bar.jpg);}

.content-portfolio:hover{width:400px; height:400px; background:url(http://somdow.com/images/sitePortThumbs/2882films-video-production.png);}
```

PS: here is the fiddle[ http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/d2Yf9/ ]
,the images are from my own website, obviously just change the url to your own.

Edit: Essentially, from the code i added, you dont need any of it, all you need to do is the same thing you did, just change the url on the hover and you are set to go.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this (You will need jquery):

html

```
<body>
<button id="button" >Change Background</button>
<div class="content-portfolio">your content</div>

</body>
```

css

```
.content-portfolio{
    background-image: url('path/to/your/image.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

js

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','#button',function(){
    $('.content-portfolio').css('background','path/to/your/image.jpg');
});
$(document).on('mouseout','#button',function(){
    $('.content-portfolio').css('background','path/to/your/otherimage.jpg');
});
```

Also you can create two classes with different backgrounds, and you can add or remove class through jquery

Comment: What if `.content-portfolio` is not a child element of `#yourbutton`?

Comment: "You will need jquery" is never the answer

Answer (score -2):

You need jQuery.

Create two classes and add two jquery methods to your button. One css class with the hover image and another class without.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your-button").on("mouseover", function(){
        $("#content-portfolio").toggleClass("back2");
    }).on("mouseout", function(){
        $("#content-portfolio").toggleClass("back2");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.back1 {
    background-image: url(../files/portfolio/event.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.back2 {
    background-image: url(../files/portfolio/event2.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I think a javascript only solution would be better, you can change that *You need jQuery* for something like *Another solution would be using jQuery* or something that notes that this is not the only possible solution.