# Display Listbox On Textbox Hover By CSS

Tags: css, asp.net

I am not able to display listbox on mouse hover on textbox as below

```
<table id="Search">
    <tr>
       <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="topics" CssClass="TT"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ListBox ID="LstBox" CssClass="LB" runat="server" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mahesh" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mahendra" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Kirti" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
td .LB
{
   display:none;
   position:relative;
}

td TT:hover  .LB
{
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
}
```

How to display listbox on mouse hover on textbox?.

Comment: I am not sure it can be done through css but it can be done through java-script or jQuery.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ, Ok than suggest it. but like to know the reason why is it not possible in css?.

Comment: I have seen some [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class) where it is shown how to handle other control css on other control hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can do it like this.
>
> HTML

```
<table id="Search">
<tr>
<td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="topics" CssClass="TT"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:ListBox ID="LstBox" CssClass="LB" runat="server" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mahesh" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mahendra" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Kirti" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

> CSS

```
 table tr td{
    position:relative;
    }

    .TT{
    /*It's optional to provide it these three property.*/
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;  /*Change values according to your adjustments*/
    top:0;   /*Change values according to your adjustments*/
    }

    .LB{
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;  /*Change values according to your adjustments*/
    top:0;   /*Change values according to your adjustments*/
    display:none;
    }

    /*If you want to keep it visible, better use on :focus Pseudo class*/
    table td:focus .LB,table td:hover .LB
    {
    display:block;
    }
```

> **OR better option**
>   JQUERY
>   /*This will work directly with your textbox. Don't forget to add jQuery latest version.*/

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".TT").hover(
                  function () {
                      $('.LB').css('display','block');
                  }, function () {
                      $('.LB').css('display', 'none');
                  }
                );
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: @user2741987 I changed it. "table td:focus .LB,table td:hover .LB". As "table td" is the parent for both of them so, css hover pseudo classes will only affect when you use hover on parent. 
otherwise Us jQuery to do it with input box.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
td .TT:hover .LB
{
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
}
```

References: [Use :hover to modify the css of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class)