# mouseover / mouseout for multiple elements but the same image

Tags: jquery

I have 2 questions...

(1) I have an icon I want to appear above my navigation elements when hovered over [similar to the magic line] but instead of having the icon placed multiple times above each navigation element, I just want to place the icon once and have it repeated when hovered over?

(2) I am still a noob when it comes to jQuery, so my code is way to long for my liking. Please find the code below that I would like to shorten and if I could get some feed back and suggestions that would be great. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sheep1, #sheep2, #sheep3, #sheep4, #sheep5").hide();

    $("#about").mouseover(function(){
        $("#sheep1").show();
    });

    $("#about").mouseout(function(){
        $("#sheep1").hide();
    });

    $("#graphics").mouseover(function(){
        $("#sheep2").show();
    });

    $("#graphics").mouseout(function(){
        $("#sheep2").hide();
    });

    $("#web").mouseover(function(){
        $("#sheep3").show();
    });

    $("#web").mouseout(function(){
        $("#sheep3").hide();
    });

    $("#blog").mouseover(function(){
        $("#sheep4").show();
    });

    $("#blog").mouseout(function(){
        $("#sheep4").hide();
    });

    $("#contact").mouseover(function(){
        $("#sheep5").show();
    });

    $("#contact").mouseout(function(){
        $("#sheep5").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: To start with, I would give the images a common class so you can attach the events (`mouseenter mouseover`, `mouseleave mouseout`) handlers in a single selector.

Comment: Are all these elements with IDs starting with `sheep` basically the same, but just repeated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give your elements a data-target attribute:

```
<div id="about" data-target="#sheep1">
```

And then in your events you can do:

```
$("#about, #graphics, #web, #blog")
  .on("mouseover", function(e) {
     var target = $(this).data("target");
     $(target).show();
  }).on("mouseout", function(e) {
     var target = $(this).data("target");
     $(target).hide();   
  });
```

This way, you attach to all the objects at once, and each affects the correct target.

Answer (score 1):

why use jquery when you can use only css??

example:

```
#about:hover #sheep1{
   display:none;
}​
```

more info [Use :hover to modify the css of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a class to all the sheep `class='sheep'`
2. Either add line to css `.sheep {display:none;}` or jquery `$('.sheep').hide();`
3. Change your sheep class to mimic the hover id: not `id='sheep1` but `class='sheep aboutSheep'`
4. Add a class to your hover elements `class='do_hover'`
5. Your hover function:

   ```
   $(".do_hover").hover(function(){

     var theSheep = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + 'Sheep';
     $(theSheep).toggle();

   });
   ```

Comment: Unless I didn't get it, wouldn't this create multiple elements sharing the same `id`? _not id='sheep1 but id='aboutSheep'_

Comment: i didn't notice the multiple references to a single sheep. no worries, just make this a class, not an id. i will update my answer.

Comment: This answer is more about thinking about how to minimize your code by thinking about how to name things effectively.