# How to make a button affect another element

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my light switch (top left) change the background-color of my navigation bar when clicked, how would i do that? This is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #222;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #222;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.nav ul li img {
  width: 12px;
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav ul li a,
visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #099;
}
.navhome {
  color: #099;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #099;
}
.navother {
  color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130%;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bdaimg {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.bdaimg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.nu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.bdaimg2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.bdaimg2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
/*Light Switch*/

label {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px/25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
}
label:hover {
  background: #ddca7e;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input#lightswitch {
  position: fixed;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
input#lightswitch + .content {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
/*Switched Off*/

input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  background-color: #222;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.5s ease-in;
}
input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Beijing Dance Academy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bda.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navother" href="Home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CR.html">Cultural Revolution</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navhome" href="BDA.html">Beijing Dance Academy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CNY.html">Chinese New Year</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="lightswitch">Light Switch</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lightswitch" />
  <div class="content">
    <img src="bda.png" alt="BDA" class="bdaimg">
    <p>
      <h2>Beijing Dance Academy</h2>
      Beijing Dance Academy, or BDA, was the first professional dance school founded in China, in 1954. The academy was helped by Soviet Russia in building the academy and the techniques they used to learn dance. Although Russia helped with the Beijing Dance
      Academy, China's repressive Communist government forbidded Russian presence in the school. The Beijing Dance Academy soon opened back up to all people from around the world when, in 1976, China's Communist leader, Mao Zedong, died.
      <br>
      <br>Several times a year, Beijing Dance Academy holds auditions to be accepted into the school, for more disadvantaged areas officals come around small towns and schools and pick out children of age, the academy initially only accepted students from
      ages 11 to 18 but eventually the age range expanded. They then test the student's basic body abilities. More than 2,000 children audition to be accepted into the academy but only 1 in every 20 make the cut. Majority of the children in the academy
      are Chinese but the academy has an additional program that allows international students to apply.
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>
    A Day in the Life of a Student
  </h3>
      A day of a Beijing Dance Academy student starts with basic warm-ups and stretches such as flexibility exercises and drills for turns and jumps. After breakfast, the students have a ballet technique class followed by character dance or pas de deux exercises.
      Then after lunch, the students study normal subjects such as mathematics or Chinese for 3 hours. In the afternoon, they have repertory classes or study or do homework. The Beijing Dance Academy is run for the whole week...
    </p>
    <p class="nu">
      INCLUDING SATURDAY AND SUNDAY!
      <img src="sadface.png" alt="SpongebobSadFace" class="bdaimg2">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to write your code here and additionally you can share pastebin link.

Comment: I don't know how to add code. :P

Comment: Go through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). There's very easy guide to help you about asking questions.

Comment: Inserted code into question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it without javascript.
You have to make three changes in your code
1. Place the `#lightswitch` before the `.nav` container

```
  <label for="lightswitch">Light Switch</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lightswitch" />
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navother" href="Home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CR.html">Cultural Revolution</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navhome" href="BDA.html">Beijing Dance Academy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CNY.html">Chinese New Year</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="bda.png" alt="BDA" class="bdaimg">
    <p>
      <h2>Beijing Dance Academy</h2>
      Beijing Dance Academy, or BDA, was the first professional dance school founded in China, in 1954. The academy was helped by Soviet Russia in building the academy and the techniques they used to learn dance. Although Russia helped with the Beijing Dance
      Academy, China's repressive Communist government forbidded Russian presence in the school. The Beijing Dance Academy soon opened back up to all people from around the world when, in 1976, China's Communist leader, Mao Zedong, died.
      <br>
      <br>Several times a year, Beijing Dance Academy holds auditions to be accepted into the school, for more disadvantaged areas officals come around small towns and schools and pick out children of age, the academy initially only accepted students from
      ages 11 to 18 but eventually the age range expanded. They then test the student's basic body abilities. More than 2,000 children audition to be accepted into the academy but only 1 in every 20 make the cut. Majority of the children in the academy
      are Chinese but the academy has an additional program that allows international students to apply.
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>
    A Day in the Life of a Student
  </h3>
      A day of a Beijing Dance Academy student starts with basic warm-ups and stretches such as flexibility exercises and drills for turns and jumps. After breakfast, the students have a ballet technique class followed by character dance or pas de deux exercises.
      Then after lunch, the students study normal subjects such as mathematics or Chinese for 3 hours. In the afternoon, they have repertory classes or study or do homework. The Beijing Dance Academy is run for the whole week...
    </p>
    <p class="nu">
      INCLUDING SATURDAY AND SUNDAY!
      <img src="sadface.png" alt="SpongebobSadFace" class="bdaimg2">
    </p>
  </div>
```

2. Add css for `top` of `label` below the `.nav`

   ```
   label {
     display: block;
     height: 25px;
     width: 100px;
     background: white;
     text-align: center;
     font: 14px/25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     margin: 20px 0;
     position: absolute;
       top:50px;
   }
   ```
3. Add css similar to the `input#lightswitch ~ .content` for `input#lightswitch ~ .nav`

   ```
           input#lightswitch ~ .content {
         background-color: #bdbdbd;
         transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
       }
       /*Switched Off*/

       input#lightswitch:checked ~ .content {
         background-color: #222;
         transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
       }
       input#lightswitch:checked ~ .nav{
         background-color: #eee;
         transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
       }
       input#lightswitch:checked ~ .nav ul li {
         background-color: #eee;
         transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
       }
       input#lightswitch:checked ~ .nav ul li a.navother {
         color: #111;
         transition: color 0.5s ease-in;
       }
       input#lightswitch:checked ~ .content {
         color: white;
         transition: color 0.5s ease-in;
       }
       input#lightswitch:checked ~ .content {
         color: white;
         transition: color 0.5s ease-in;
       }
   ```

You can see the working fiddle here

[See woking fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpt1bcop/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to handle this using `jQuery`:

```
$('#lightswitch').on('click', function() {
   $('nav').css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

Best

Comment: Is there any way to do this with pure CSS. I am trying to avoid JS at all costs because, let's face it, it's crap.

Comment: @Amorris JS is crap? I really hope you're kidding. Unless you like mostly static pages that have little to no functionality.

Comment: Theres much better than JS

Comment: You may want to look at this response with a `:checked` pseudo class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class

Comment: Even though I am trying to avoid jQuery. I will use this. Thank you.

Comment: @Amorris Yes you can achieve this by pure css. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by pure javascript.

```
document.querySelector('#lightswitch').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('nav').style["background-color"] = "Green Color Code";
});
```