# How to highlight all elements with the same css class when you hover over an element? I want to add mouse effect like Zoom In - Elementor WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I want to add mouse effects like ZOOM IN on each pricing table; However, I made the pricing tables manually so each row is not related to the previous one. I read that I have to do it using javascript, I gave each Elementor column a class name, for example, the number of users and dashboards under BASIC will have the same class. I tried a code and I was able to change the background color, but how can I add a zoom effect? I didn't find a way to change the height and width in a function.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luHNF.png)

Thank you!

Comment: For zoom effect use `transform: scale(112.5%)`

Answer (score -1):

As referenced in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483891/10013076

You can consider two things:

1.

```
.item:hover .wrapper {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}​
```

2. 

```
.item:hover ~ .wrapper {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}​
```